# Django Error While Submitting Forms

Tags: python, django

Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by .wrapper at 0x75abfcd8> Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/pi/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper fn(*args, **kwargs) File "/home/pi/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run self.check(display_num_errors=True) File "/home/pi/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in check include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks, File "/home/pi/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in _run_checks return checks.run_checks(**kwargs) File "/home/pi/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 73, in run_checks new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs) File "/home/pi/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver) File "/home/pi/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', []) File "/home/pi/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in get res = instance.dict[self.name] = self.func(instance) File "/home/pi/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 536, in url_patterns patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module) File "/home/pi/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in get res = instance.dict[self.name] = self.func(instance) File "/home/pi/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 529, in urlconf_module return import_module(self.urlconf_name) File "/home/pi/.venv/lib/python3.5/importlib/init.py", line 126, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) File "", line 986, in _gcd_import File "", line 969, in _find_and_load File "", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "", line 673, in _load_unlocked File "", line 673, in exec_module File "", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed File "/home/pi/tango_with_django_project/tango_with_django_project/urls.py", line 25, in url(r'^rango/', include('rango.urls')), File "/home/pi/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module) File "/home/pi/.venv/lib/python3.5/importlib/init.py", line 126, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) File "", line 986, in _gcd_import File "", line 969, in _find_and_load File "", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "", line 673, in _load_unlocked File "", line 673, in exec_module File "", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed File "/home/pi/tango_with_django_project/rango/urls.py", line 2, in from rango import views File "/home/pi/tango_with_django_project/rango/views.py", line 5, in from rango.forms import CategoryForm File "/home/pi/tango_with_django_project/rango/forms.py", line 4, in class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm): File "/home/pi/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 243, in new "needs updating." % name django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited; form CategoryForm needs updating.

Here is my forms.py

from django import forms from rango.models import Page, Category

class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm): name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter the category name.") views = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0) likes = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)

class Meta:
    model = Category
class PageForm(forms.ModelForm): title = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter the title of the page.") url = forms.URLField(max_length=200, help_text="Please enter the URL of the page.") views = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)

class Meta:
    model = Page
    fields = ('title', 'url', 'views')
here is my views.py

from django.template import RequestContext from django.shortcuts import render_to_response from rango.models import Category from rango.models import Page from rango.forms import CategoryForm

def index(request): context = RequestContext(request) category_list = Category.objects.order_by('-likes')[:5] context_dict = {'categories': category_list} for category in category_list: category.url = category.name.replace(' ', '_') return render_to_response('rango/index.html', context_dict, context)

def about(request): context = RequestContext(request) context_dict = {'boldmessage': "I am bold font from the context"} return render_to_response('rango/about.html', context_dict, context)

def category(request, category_name_url): context = RequestContext(request) category_name = category_name_url.replace('_', ' ') context_dict = {'category_name': category_name} try: category = Category.objects.get(name=category_name) pages = Page.objects.filter(category=category) context_dict['pages'] = pages context_dict['category'] = category except Category.DoesNotExist: pass return render_to_response('rango/category.html', context_dict, context)

def add_category(request): context = RequestContext(request)

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CategoryForm(request.POST)

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save(commit=True)
    return index(request)
else:
    print (form.errors)
```

else:
    form = CategoryForm()

return render_to_response('rango/add_category.html', {'form': form}, context)

Comment: You should select your code and use CTRL + K to format it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `fields` or `exclude` attribute to the form class

```
class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['name']
```

Seems like you don't have a model named `Category` in that case you should inherit from `forms.Form`

```
class CategoryForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter the category name.")
```